# Issue tying to read environment variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, service, environment-variables

Hi I'm trying to read an environment variable in python, if I execute my script from console with:
`python3 myScript.py` everything goes ok, but I need to run this script as a service in Ubuntu, in this case, the script can't get the environment variable. Anyone has past for the same issue? I noticed that when i'm trying to read the mongo URI from environment.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to achieve that is passing the environment variable or environment file to the service file, in my case I added this line to my service file:
`EnvironmentFile = /etc/environment`

Comment: FWIW, the solution you found may or may not be correct. If the env var is set in your *~/.bashrc*, for example, then your solution doesn't work. This basically boils down to understanding how environment variables work in a UNIX like operating system.